# Converting flex/bison parser for use in the browser

Tags: javascript, c, flex-lexer, yacc

I've made a simple programming language and compiler using Flex and Yacc, and I want to be able to convert my code for use in the browser.

I've already taken a look at projects like Jison, but I don't think that would work for me as I'd then have to maintain two different codebases.

Looking around some more, I'm pretty sure compiling my compiler to WebAssembly and running that in the browser would be the solution. Only problem is that I'm not sure how to go about doing that. Can the Flex library that I pass when linking the lexer and the parser together (-lfl) also be compiled along with my compiler?

I really have no experience with WASM and I'm pretty new to Flex/Yacc too, so there may be some very obvious solution, but I can't seem to find anything.

If you want to take a look at my code: https://github.com/inobulles/aqua-compiler/tree/master/langs/amber

Thanks alot for your time!

Comment: You’ll probably want to use Emscripten: https://emscripten.org

Comment: Isn't emscripten a compiler for wasm?

Comment: I thought you wanted to port your compiler to the browser, am I wrong?

Comment: Not at all, but I'm not sure I understand what emscripten is. Isn't it a compiler that compiles for wasm?

Comment: Emscripten compiles C/C++ code to WebAssembly, which you can run in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing of much use in `-lfl`; you shouldn't need it in any real application.

If you don't define `yywrap()` in your flex file, then add

```
%option noyywrap
```

to your flex prologue, so that flex doesn't put a reference to `yywrap` into the generated code. If you do define `yywrap` then you already don't need `-lfl`, but you still might think about `%option noyywrap` so that you don't need the definition.

I don't know how WASM deals with `stdio.h` functions; presumably, your intent is to use some other mechanism to feed text into your lexer, but the generated code will still contain references to standard library I/O functions (as does the code generated by Bison).

Comment: Oh ok thanks alot. Although I haven't yet used WASM much, I would assume that most of the standard functions are supported.